# Highlight Current Page on DYnamic Navigation PHP Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, content-management-system

I get my dynamic navigation menu from the database because I have a CMS, so here's my code:

```
<ul>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, DESCRIPTION FROM menu where VISIBLE='1' ORDER BY `order` ASC") or die(mysql_error());                   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
printf('<li>%s %s </a></li> ', $row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']);
}
?>
```

i have to add this inside the li element. This code should also come from the database

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="current"';?>
```

how should i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using PHP. `printf()` with formatting codes is pointless, UNLESS you're using the actual formatting options for numbers. But if you insist, then add in another format code, `<li%s>%s ...` and fill it in with your css class if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
<ul>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, DESCRIPTION 
FROM menu where VISIBLE='1' ORDER BY `order` ASC") 
or die(mysql_error());                   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) $code = 'class="current"'; else $code = '';
printf('<li %s>%s %s </a></li> ', $code, $row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']);
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the response sir, but it will make all the navs active

Comment: wait a minute  i'll try it

Comment: Well then tell us how the CMS routing works. Can you give one or better two example URLs?

Comment: just as i thought, it made all the navs active

Comment: this code
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="current"';?>
should be within a row

Comment: so the code will look like this
 
<?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT CSTYLE,id, name, DESCRIPTION FROM menu where VISIBLE='1' ORDER BY `order` ASC") or die(mysql_error());
       
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   printf('<li%s)>%s %s </a></li> ',$row['CSTYLE'],$row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']);
  }
 ?>

Comment: It depends on the CMS' routing. E. g. if a URL looks like http://localhost/cms/index.php?page=imprint you can do: 
if ($result['name'] == $_GET['page']) $code = $result['CSTYLE']; else $code = ''; printf('<li %s>%s %s </a></li> ', $code, $row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']);